# How to change the atribute in my click event?

Tags: c#, events, windows-phone-7, click

I have a list of grids and 2 buttons in each grid. One of these buttons is a delete button, so I need to send the `Coletor` to my click event to change it atribute. How can I pass my `Coletor` to my click event?

My method that is creating the grids:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString["email"] != null)
        {
            email = NavigationContext.QueryString["email"];
        }

        List<Grid> listaGrids = new List<Grid>();

        int i = 0;

        AppDataContext db = new AppDataContext();

        Pessoa pessoa = db.Pessoas.Single(c => c.Email == email);

        foreach (Coletor coletor in pessoa.Coletores)
        {
            if (coletor.Ativado == true)
            {
                Grid aux = new Grid();
                ColumnDefinition c1 = new ColumnDefinition();
                ColumnDefinition c2 = new ColumnDefinition();
                ColumnDefinition c3 = new ColumnDefinition();

                aux.Width = 440;
                aux.Height = 80;

                aux.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

                c1.Width = new System.Windows.GridLength(220);
                c2.Width = new System.Windows.GridLength(80);
                c3.Width = new System.Windows.GridLength(80);



                coletorAux = coletor;

                aux.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c1);
                aux.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c2);
                aux.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c3);

                RowDefinition r1 = new RowDefinition();

                aux.RowDefinitions.Add(r1);

                HyperlinkButton aux2 = new HyperlinkButton();
                aux2.Content = coletor.Nome;
                aux2.FontSize = 42;
                aux2.NavigateUri = new Uri("/OcorrenciasPage.xaml?coletorId=" + coletor.Id.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                i++;

                Button btnEdit = new Button();

                var brush = new ImageBrush();

                brush.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/icons/edit.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                btnEdit.Background = brush;

                btnEdit.Width = 80;
                btnEdit.Height = 80;

                btnEdit.Click += btnEdit_Click;

                Button btnDelete = new Button();

                ImageBrush brush2 = new ImageBrush();

                brush2.ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/icons/delete.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                btnDelete.Background = brush2;

                btnDelete.Width = 80;
                btnDelete.Height = 80;

                btnDelete.Click += btnDelete_Clickrr;

                Grid.SetColumn(aux2, 0);
                Grid.SetColumn(btnEdit, 1);
                Grid.SetColumn(btnDelete, 2);
                Grid.SetRow(aux2, 0);
                Grid.SetRow(btnEdit, 0);
                Grid.SetRow(btnDelete, 0);



                aux.Children.Add(aux2);
                aux.Children.Add(btnEdit);
                aux.Children.Add(btnDelete);

                listaGrids.Add(aux);
            }
        }

        ListBox coletores = new ListBox();
        coletores.ItemsSource = listaGrids;
        stcList.Children.Add(coletores);

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

And my click event:

```
void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente excluir esse coletor?", "Confirmação", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand. I assume you want to delete the selected item in a (list? grid? anything else?) and delete it, so you don't have to pass nothing to your button, check which element is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign the Coletor to the button's Tag property

```
btnDelete.Tag = coletor;
```

and then get that back in the event:

```
var coletor = ((sender as Button).Tag as Coletor);
```

It's a little bit clunky, but it'll work.

Comment: A common use for the Tag property is to store data that is closely associated with the control. For example, if you have a control that displays information about a customer, you might store a DataSet that contains the customer's order history in that control's Tag property so the data can be accessed quickly.

[Control.Tag Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @MVCDS: I find data in tags a bit "anonymous". They don't explain what they are, you have to know already. If a different coder came along, they might accidentally use the tag for something else. But it's not wrong to use them. Personal choice and circumstances, I guess. :)

Comment: but the only other way I could think is what I have answered, that falls on the same problem, but polutes the HTML, what it's worse, that's why I voted up your answer.

Comment: Yes - needs must; a solution is a solution. I just have a bit of an OCD 'hang up' about code being self-explanatory. But, unfortunately for me, that isn't always an option. And thanks for the up-vote. :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the button an attribute...

```
//after creating the button
btnDelete.Attributes.Add('coletorId', coletorId.ToString());
```

...recover what uou need it on the sender

```
//inside btnDelete_Click
Button btnDelete = (Button) sender;
string attr = btnDelete.Attributes['coletorId'];
Guid id = Guid.Parse(attr);
Coletor = db.Coletores.SingleOrDefault(p => p.id == id);
```

.NEt API may be wrong, but I think the general idea is right.